# Android JSON performance issue

Tags: java, android, json, performance

I have performance problems with parsing a `JSON` String back to the java object.
Here is the code:

```
public List<BusinessObject> transferToDomain(String pJSON) {
        List<BusinessObject> lAllBusinessObject = new ArrayList<BusinessObject>();
        if (null == pJSON || pJSON.equals("")){
            return lAllBusinessObject;
        }
        JSON lJSON = JSONSerializer.toJSON(pJSON); <-- LONG RUNTIME HERE!
        if (lJSON.isEmpty()) {
            return lAllBusinessObject;
        } else {
            if (lJSON.isArray()) {
                JSONArray lJSONArray = (JSONArray) lJSON;
                for (Object lObject : lJSONArray) {
                    JSONObject lJSONObject = (JSONObject) lObject;
                    lAllBusinessObject.add(doTransfer(lJSONObject));
                }
            } else {
                JSONObject json = (JSONObject) lJSON;
                BusinessObject lBusinessObject = doTransfer(json);
                if (null != lBusinessObject) {
                    lAllBusinessObject.add(lBusinessObject);
                }
            }
        }
        return lAllBusinessObject;
    }
```

If I run my test method with 200 test objects(inside pJSON) the whole operation is done in less then 2 seconds.
If I run the same method in the `Android` emulator with 200 objects received from my server the whole operation needs more then 4 minutes!!!

It has something to do with that line of code:

```
JSON lJSON = JSONSerializer.toJSON(pJSON);
```

but I dont understand why my `JUnit` method is fast and the emulator is realy slow in executing the method?

I am using `json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar`

Need some advice.

Thanks in advance

Stefan

Comment: Have you tried running it in a HAXM (Intel Atom x86) emulator instance or on a phone/tablet?

Comment: from Device manager: CPU/ABI = ARM (armeabi-v7a)

Comment: Try using HAXM with Intel Atom x86... Should be much faster and give you a better idea if there really is an issue here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason for the slow performance.
If I run the application not in the debug mode, the performance is really fast(<5 seconds).
It's a debug mode issue in my eyes.

Comment: I am also seeing approximately 16x longer json parse times in debug builds versus release. This is using the stock json library on a Galaxy Tab 4.

Answer (score -1):

Why you don't use Jackson library. It has the fastest json parsing capability comparing with Gson or other else. It has all functionalities, json to class obj, obj to json. Use Jackson and test your performance.

Comment: change the library is one solution, but I want to know why the emulator needs 4 minutes for parsing the json string to object and my junit 2 seconds...

Comment: It takes time because it depends upon network accessibility, processor speed, memory capability etc. So that it takes tong time.

Comment: No. IMO Parsing a json string should be done in less seconds. Especialy for my code